# Two Counters Within Smartys Foreach Statement

Tags: php, html, smarty

Can any help me out.

I'm trying and put 2 smarty counters / `{counter}` within a foreach statement / `{foreach}` for exmaple.

Now if i only use one counter like this.

```
{foreach from=bla_bla key=id item=val name=titles}
<h1 class="title"> Title {counter} </h1>
{/foreach}
```

It works great but if i put in 2 counters like this.

```
{foreach from=bla_bla key=id item=val name=titles}
<h1 class="title"> Title {counter} </h1>
<h2 class="subtitle"> Sub Title {counter} </h2>
{/foreach}
```

The h1 title starts counting in odd numbers for example.

```
Title 1
Title 3
Title 5
```

And so on, Can anyone help me correct this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the smarty counter interval to 1

```
{counter start=0 skip=1 assign="count"}
```

in your case:

```
{foreach from=bla_bla key=id item=val name=titles}
<h1 class="title"> Title {counter start=0 skip=1 assign="count"} </h1>
<h2 class="subtitle"> Sub Title {counter} </h2>
{/foreach}
```